# Wordpress "301 Moved Permanently" Problem

Tags: apache2, wordpress

"wget localhost" gave me correct Wordpress blog html.
But "wget serverip" outside of local network gave me 
"HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently" Error..!

And when I make index.html file at /var/www/html, "wget serverip" outside of local network gave me correct html.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

Just edited wp-config.php and theme's function.php to use 8080 port

thanks